# How to Add Federated engine after installing Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, storage-engine, ubuntu

I have Mysql 5.5.18
and upon show engines:

```
show engines;
+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

as you see federated engine is not one of the list. i need to enable it!! any idea of why BLACKHOLE, FEDERATED, and ARCHIVE engines are missing from the list? and how can i **add/enable** them?
**EDIT**
I have ubuntu 11.10 and installed mysql from ppa ... i have added the following to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you have installed your mysql server.

Comment: question has been edited

Comment: How were you able to find a PPA with 5.5? I have been looking for almost a day now

Comment: Hwllo Dark, check https://launchpad.net

Comment: Be careful. Federated is disabled by default since has some unsolved bugs. Why do you need it?

Comment: i need to use join with a table located on another server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution...
there is a plugin already available at

`/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_federated.so`

i just logged in to mysql as root and run the following query

`mysql>install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so';`

then i added federated to my.cnf and restarted mysql

Comment: Is this applicable for mysql installed from binary distribution rather than source ???

Answer (score 3):

**If Default installation/binary installation**

In My opinion the `BLACKHOLE , ARCHIVE`  are installed and enabled by default when you install the Mysql server.

but the `FEDERATED` is not enabled by default.For that do like this

You can enable it manually you have edit your my.cnf file.edit my.cnf and in the [mysqld] section, add the line:

```
federated
```

Now restart the Mysql server.

For adding `Archive` go to link http://timanovsky.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/enabling-archive-storage-engine-in-ius-mysql-5-1/

**If you have installed from source then you was supposed to do like this:**

**For Blackhole:** invoke configure with the `--with-blackhole-storage-engine` option.

**For  Archieve:**  invoke configure with the `--with-archive-storage-engine` option

**For Federated:**  invoke configure with the  `--with-federated-storage-engine` option

Comment: Abdul, If i installed mysql from compiled binaries, then how should i get federated engine active... I think i should resintall from source or is there any other option....

Comment: Just Add a line federated in Your my.cnf and restart the server.

Comment: Manaf, I missed to inform one more detail. When I hit "SHOW ENGINES", I saw "NO" for federated engine which means the binary is not compiled with the support for that engine. How to proceed in this scenario...

Answer (score 2):

I know the post is a little old, but it seems that many people are having issues with federated engines.

When the mysql binaries are installed via yum, you already have the HA (High Availability) plugins.  You simply need to load the plugins within the mysql CLI.

Here is the basic process:

Start mysqld if it is not already started.  Make sure 'federated' is NOT in /etc/my.cnf at this point.

EX: At this time, /etc/my.cnf will look like this from a standard YUM install....

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Log into the mysql CLI with root (or another account with sufficient privilege).

Type: `show engines;`

You should see no FEDERATED engine at this point, like this:

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To enable the federate engine, type the following:

```
install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so'
```

NOW, when you 'show engines' you will see the FEDERATED Engine, but turned off...

It will look like this:

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                             | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can now safely add the line 'federated' to the /etc/my.cnf file like this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
federated

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Restart mysqld (service mysqld restart, etc...)

After the restart, go back in to the mysql CLI.

Type `show engines;`

You should now see the FEDERATED Engine available and with SUPPORT as YES.

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| FEDERATED  | YES     | Federated MySQL storage engine                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And you are done...go forth and create federate tables...

Good luck!

Email me with any questions...happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

On ML with the MySQL 5.5 (current) all I needed to do was:

- Copy one of the existing files from /usr/local/mysql/support-files/
  to /etc/my.cnf
- Add 'federated'(without quotes) to the [mysqld] section (not the end
  of the my.cnf file)
- Restart MySQL

This might also be useful for those that want an automated way to declare tables: http://sylnsr.blogspot.com/2012/11/auto-constructing-ddl-for-mysql.html

Comment: Could you disclose what ML is?  I can't decide whether it has relevance here or not :)

Comment: OS X Mountain Lion. I believe this has relevance since there are many people that use MySQL on OS X Mountain Lions. When searching for "mysql on ml" => https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+on+ml

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mysql 8.0 in ubuntu 20.04, All the previous responses tackle the issue pretty well, i ran install plugin inside mysql, then i added `federated` to the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file, but when i try to get into the mysql shell, i get the following error :

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown option '--federated'.
```

If this happens to you, it probably means you added federated in the wrong configuration file, this is the contents of my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` :

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

in my case, the correct location to add the federated option was `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` , this is what it looks like once the federated flag is added :

```
[mysqld]
federated
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
log-error   = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

If you can't locate the files i mentioned or the mysql tree is different in your system, make sure you're adding **federated** under **[mysqld], not [mysql]**